# Python finding a pattern in a file

Tags: python

I want to loop through a file and search for patterns ("red", "yellow", or "green") in the same order i.e., it should return red if it is found, else yellow, else green. I am not having success as python comes back not finding any patterns, but the string yellow is in fact in the file:

```
with open("/tmp/store_results") as results:
    for line in open(results, "r"):
        if "red" in line:
            color = "red"
        elif "yellow" in line:
            color = "yellow"
        else:
            color = "green"

print "Color is %s" % (color)

results.close()

$ Color is green
```

Testing for other strings it is obvious it is not identifying any patterns at all.

Comment: have you heard of regular expression. `re module` in python

Comment: can you show us your file???

Comment: shouldn't you be doing for line in complete, instead of opening another file called results?

Comment: and of course if last line has no red or yellow your color will be green, as per your code, regardless of what you have in other lines!

Comment: this has nothing to do with regex, this is just subtring matching.

Comment: importing re and have tried to use re.match and re.search, same results.

Comment: @user3885927 you are absolutely right. In bash I could grep a file in its entirety, but in python seems the only way to search for a pattern is line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indenting your `print` statement wrong; as it currently stands, it will print the result for only the last line (because the value of color is over-written in each subsequent run), and my guess is the last line doesn't have red or yellow.

So, you need align the print statement within the `for` block.

```
with open("/tmp/store_results", "r") as complete:
    for line in open(results, "r"):
        if "red" in line:
            color = "red"
        elif "yellow" in line:
            color = "yellow"
        else:
            color = "green"
        print "Color is %s" % (color)
```

***EDIT***

To check the color in the whole file, with priority for red suprseding yellow, and for yellow superseeding green, you can do

```
filename = "/tmp/store_results"
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    if "red" in file_content:
        color = "red"
    elif "yellow" in file_content:
        color = "yellow"
    else:
        color = "green"
    print "Color is %s" % (color)
```

Comment: He's got bigger problems than that: your fix is going to output one color per line (usually green).

Comment: Correct @pjz. Python has to allow some way to read an entire file first and begin testing for the color in it. Red superseding yellow, yellow green.

Comment: @aekandem Check edits. Let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: I've tried a million different things but as soon as I read your bit of code @mu, I knew it would work. Thanks so much! Hope this helps out others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over *every* line of the file and reassigning `color` every time.  Therefore, even if "yellow" gets found in one particular line, the loop then continues onto subsequent lines that presumably do not contain the word "yellow". Each time it hits a line that doesn't contain "red" or "yellow",  the variable `color` gets overwritten with the value `"green"`.  So you're throwing away your information about the earlier hit.

Answer (score 1):

As @jez says, you're overwriting your earlier-line hit information by assigning 'green' every line, when your description seems to indicate that you want to return one color per file, not per line.  Also, your use of `open()` is just wrong.  You need to rearrange the assignments like this:

```
color = "green"
for line in open("/tmp/store_results", "r"):
    if "red" in line:
        color = "red"
    elif "yellow" in line:
        color = "yellow"
print "Color is %s" % (color)
```

So color is initialized to green and remains green iff neither of the other colors is found.  Note that if they're both found, the last one found will 'win' because it wil overwrite `color` last.  For the first one found to 'win' add a `break` statement after `color` is assigned to `"red"` or `"yellow"`.

Comment: Thanks @pjz, I get 'TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found' which I have gotten before and makes so sense, b/c it should be expecting a file.